# in jqgrid, is there anyway to have an auto calculated width of editGridRow() popup

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqmodal

to edit a row in **jqgrid**, i use **editGridRow**.  i see that you can pass in a width like this:

```
ondblClickRow: function (rowid) {
        jQuery('#grid').editGridRow(rowid, true, { width: 600 });

    }
```

but is there anyway to have jqgrid auto calculate the width (based on the width of the largest field length) by using "auto" or something like that ??

Comment: Well I would tell you to try `{width: 'auto'}`, but it seems you did try it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setting of `{width: "auto"}` work good in all modern web browsers excepting Internet Explorer of course.

The following CSS solve the problem at least in IE8/IE9:

```
<style type="text/css">
    div.ui-jqdialog-content table.EditTable { width:auto; float:left; }
    form.FormGrid { float:left; width:auto; }
    div.ui-jqdialog-content > span > table.EditTable {
        width:auto; clear: left; float:right
    }
</style>
```

The corresponding demo you will find [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/FormAutoWidth.htm).

The solution for "retro" versions of IE can be more complicated and should be based on direct setting of widths of different components of the edit form. The rough solution based on the way is [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/FormAutoWidth6.htm).

Comment: @ooo: Hello! Do you tested my suggestion? I wrote my answer 4 days ago and you don't wrote any comment.

Comment: apologies Oleg, somehow i missed this  . .

Comment: Oleg - do you see any issues with the "rough solution" if i need to support IE7

Comment: @leora: The answer is very old and one have to change at least `div.ui-jqdialog-content > span > table.EditTable` to `div.ui-jqdialog-content>div>table.EditTable` to use it in the current version of jqGrid. To tell the truth I have no customers who use still IE7 so I try to take in considerations IE8 and higher only. The solution which works in IE7 is sure possible, but it's not a 2 min job.